# Compare table with a given string

Tags: c

I would like to compare a table i have and compare it with a given string number.
I have the table code ready and i guess it's not a problem to scan a string of 4 digits.
The table is initialize[1296][4] and I want it to compare to a given string[4].
I'm new to programming and i'm having a bit of difficulty. I'm actually building a Bulls and Cows game and I need to compare each digit of my table row to the given string of each column.
I hope i was clear with my question because it could get confusing or i'm just not explaining it right. I tried doing it but i can't seem to make it work.

Here's my table. If someone could help i would really appreciate it. Thanks.

```
void initialize(int poss[1296][4])
{
    int i=0;
    int j, k=0;
    int m;

    while (i<=5)
    {
        for (j=0; j<216 ; j++)
        {
            poss[k][0]=i;
            k++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    k=0;
    i=0;
    j=0;

    while (k<1296)
    {
        for (m=0; m<6; m++)
        {
            for (j=0; j<6; j++)
            {
                for (i=0; i<36 ; i++)
                {
                    poss[k][1]=j;
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    k=0;
    i=0;
    j=0;
    m=0;

    while (k<1296)
    {
        for (j=0; j<6; j++)
        {
            for (i=0; i<6; i++)
            {
                poss[k][2]=j;
                k++;
            }
        }

    }

    k=0;
    i=0;
    j=0;
    m=0;

    while (k<1296)
    {
        for (i=0; i<6; i++)
        {
            poss[k][3]=i;
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to reduce the number of rows they can't be shown all at once on console.
Another think you have to read the definition of the bulls and cows (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulls_and_cows). Your implimentation is not right.

Link to your code http://ideone.com/uTZf7R.

**EDIT:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void initialize(int poss[1296][4]);

int main()
{
    int table[1296][4];
    char str[5];
    char tmp[5];

    int i, j, k;
    int bull = 0;
    int cow = 0;
    initialize(table);
    printf("Enter 4 digits: ");
    gets(str);
    for (i=0; i<100; i++){
        strcpy(tmp, str);
        for (j=0; j<4; j++){
            for (k=0; k<4; k++){
                if (table[i][j]==tmp[k]-'0' && j==k){
                    tmp[k] = -1;
                    bull++;
                    break;
                }
                else if (table[i][j]==tmp[k]-'0' && j!=k){
                    tmp[k] = -1;
                    cow++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        printf ("Number: %d%d%d%d, Input: %s\n",table[i][0], table[i][1], table[i][2], table[i][3], str);
        printf ("%d bulls and %d cows\n\n", bull, cow);
        bull = 0;
        cow = 0;
    }
}

void initialize(int poss[1296][4])
{
    int i=0;
    int j, k=0;
    int m;

    while (i<=5)
    {
        for (j=0; j<216 ; j++)
        {
            poss[k][0]=i;
            k++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    k=0;
    i=0;
    j=0;

    while (k<1296)
    {
        for (m=0; m<6; m++)
        {
            for (j=0; j<6; j++)
            {
                for (i=0; i<36 ; i++)
                {
                    poss[k][1]=j;
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    k=0;
    i=0;
    j=0;
    m=0;

    while (k<1296)
    {
        for (j=0; j<6; j++)
        {
            for (i=0; i<6; i++)
            {
                poss[k][2]=j;
                k++;
            }
        }

    }

    k=0;
    i=0;
    j=0;
    m=0;

    while (k<1296)
    {
        for (i=0; i<6; i++)
        {
            poss[k][3]=i;
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

Change the variable names the way they serve you.

Note that `string[j] - '0'` is to get string[j] as an integer.

Comment: here's exactly what I want to do.I'm building a Bulls and Cows program and if let's say a number is 1100 and i put 1011 i get 1 Bull and 2 cows

Comment: Not sure if you know what my game is about but basically i want to get an answer on all the table with a given string

Comment: @YannBohbot So you want to compare your string with row of 4 digit and get the number of bulls and cows for each row.

Comment: I think that the 4 digits should be different?

Comment: basically i need to input 4 digits as a string and get the answer for each row compared.. let me know if i'm not explaining myself very well lool

Comment: on the tabke[i][k]==string[k]-'0' && j==k
subscript of pointer to function type void(int(*)[4])

Comment: There were some issues and they are corrected now.

Comment: okay i think there's a problem on my side but i cant figure it out because every time i put my table on the function i continue to get the error

Comment: What's the error generated by your debugger? or you may include your whole code.

Comment: every time i enter the table (called initialized) it gives me subscript of pointer to function type void(int(*)[4])

Comment: how can i send you the full code maybe you could spot the problem?

Comment: paste it here http://ideone.com/ and send me the link.

Comment: http://ideone.com/BYfWv9

Comment: Take a look at the edit

Comment: perfect!!! thank you very much man appreciate it i'll have a look at the code to understand it better

Comment: can you explain me table[i][j]==tmp[k]-'0'

Comment: Your absolutly need to read a book:

here we are comparing each digit of a line with one of the digits of the input to check if there is an equal. if so and the index is the same we increment the bull by 1. and if the index is different we increment the cow.

Comment: got it thanks appreciate the help and will work harder understanding everything